# Using a chrome extension, how would I read through all the HTML in a page and replace a certain part?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome Extension to do this function. I want to develop a chrome extension to do this, I do not want to inspect element and do this. I'd like to do this with javscript. Like search for a phrase through HTML and replace it. What is the most efficient and fast way to go through HTML code using a chrome extension?

For example, if I want to go through the code until the thing being read equals "10:00 AM" and then change that text to "11:00 AM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain js.  Just make sure it runs at the end of the document. In your manifest file just add  `"run_at": "document_end"`

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/10:00 AM/g, "11:00 AM");
```

Or try to target a specific section of the page like

```
var targetDOM = document.getElementById('content');
targetDOM.innerHTML = targetDOM.innerHTML.replace(/10:00 AM/g, "11:00 AM");
```

Comment: How would I search for a certain phrase. Like if I want to find all times in a web page?

Comment: The syntax for replace is ``replace(/<keywords|regex>/g, "<replacement>")`` or you might want a better enlightenment at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: When I run this, it breaks other parts of my web page.

Comment: Try to specify your target. Like ``document.getElementById('content')`` instead of selecting the entire body content.

Comment: It needs to work on all web pages, so that would not be doable. Please see my new post for information on the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988053/chrome-extension-breaks-web-pages-making-them-seemingly-load-forever

Answer (score 0):

The closest extension I can think of with this type of functionality is for Firefox called [GreaseMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey). Apparently there's also one for Chrome (though I haven't tried it) called Tampermonkey.  Hope these help.

Comment: No, I am making a Chrome Extension and want the Chrome Extension to have this functionality.

Comment: Afraid I didn't understand your question then - my apologies. Also maybe re-word your question to specify you're developing a Chrome extension?

Comment: I edited my post. If you know how, or know of any websites describing this process, let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need any extra extension in Chrome to do this. You simply open the page select the element you want to edit after highlighting simply **right click** and from the menu you can select **inspect element.**

You will see in the new code window selected code is the same for element you want to edit. Now again right click on same line of code window and **Edit as HTML**.

Change your value in this window and instantly it will be changed in page view.

I also put the link below for image which is explaining of changing [webbrands](http://thewebbrands.com/) Nav element. Sorry I can't put image here.

http://thewebbrands.com/help/chrome/01.png

Comment: I am developing a chrome extension and need to know how to do this in javascript. Please see my edited post.