# Chrome Extension breaks web pages, making them seemingly load forever?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using a chrome extension to inject code into web pages to change parts of the text if they match a certain string. It replaces the text correctly, but seems to hold the web page in an endless state of loading, and messes up certain elements on sites like Facebook.

```
    var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/10:00/g, "11:00 AM");
    } + ')();';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = actualCode;
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing the `innerHTML` will also replace attributes and text within `script` tags. To replace only text nodes inside non-script tags, use a `TreeWalker`.

```
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT),
    textNode;

while(textNode = treeWalker.nextNode()) {
  if(textNode.parentElement.tagName !== 'SCRIPT') {
    textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.replace(/10:00/g, "11:00 AM");
  }
}
```

Also, you don't need to append a script to the DOM to be able to access its contents. Content scripts can modify the DOM.

[**JSBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/yosebujime/1/edit)

Comment: Then how should I insert this script into every web page that a person visits?

Comment: If your code is part of a content script packaged in a chrome extension, chrome will execute it on every page load.